# Call methods of child class issue

Tags: ios, iphone, oop, inheritance, backend

I have

```
@interface UserBaaS : BackendlessUser
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *username;
@end

@implementation UserBaaS
@synthesize username = _username;

- (void)setUsername:(NSString *)username {
    _username = username;
    [self setProperty:@"username" object:username];
}

- (NSString *)username {
    _username = [self getProperty:@"username"];
    return _username;
}
@end
```

During my registration methods I get parent class in responce

```
[backendless.userService login:username password:password response:^(BackendlessUser *user) {

        [[Singleton sharedInstance] hideHudImmidialty];


        UserBaaS *userMy = (UserBaaS *)user;
        NSLog(@"successfully logged in for = %@", userMy.username);
        successBlock(userMy);

    }
```

But I want to call method of child class, I understand that right now the method of parent class is called. And I understand that userMy is object of BackendlessUser class (not of UserBaaS), but may be there is a way?

**How to force call the method of child class (UserBaaS) ?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a `UserBaas` instance.

Right now you have a `BackendlessUser` instance and down-casting it to a `UserBaaS` is not going to make any good. You're just lying to the compiler, but the actual runtime object will be a `BackendlessUser` anyway.

If you don't have control over the response, you can write your own initializer (or factory method) for `UserBaas` that takes a `BackendlessUser` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your user is still a BackendlessUser. Unless you send back a real UserBaaS, you won't be able to call a child method even if you try to cast it.

What you could do is init a new UserBaaS with your BackendlessUser by adding an init method in BackendlessUser class

```
-(id)initWithBackendlessUser:(BackendlessUser*)user{
     self.username = user.username
}
```

and your code should look like :

```
[backendless.userService login:username password:password response:^(BackendlessUser *user) {

    [[Singleton sharedInstance] hideHudImmidialty];
    UserBaaS *userMy = [[UserBaaS alloc] initWithBackendlessUser:user];
    NSLog(@"successfully logged in for = %@", userMy.username);
    successBlock(userMy);
}
```